# Until it stops or stopped? Reported speech question

Tags: grammar, past-tense, indirect-speech

"I told him to wait until the rain stops" or "i told him to wait until the rain stopped"

Comment: Either the first one or "I told him to wait until the rain *has* stopped"

Comment: *I told him to wait until the rain stopped.* Backshifting.

Answer (score 1):

If you are describing what happened in the past it would normally be better to say *I told him to wait until the rain stopped*. Hopefully "he" waited until the rain stopped and then did whatever he was waiting to do. If the instruction is still current because the rain has not stopped yet, you could use *I told him to wait until the rain stops*, though the other sentence would still work.

Note that in this context *stops* usually means *finishes stopping* rather than *begins stopping*.